# Android ListView with some items shown and Show More button

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm finding it hard to search for what I'm looking  for so I thought I'd try and explain it here. I currently have a Custom ListView within a ScrollView. Each ListView item contains the Branch details for a shop, i.e. street address, city, phone. I've used the `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` function shown below to get around the "scrolling a ListView in a ScrollView" problem by expanding the ListView to it's full height.

What I would like to do now is, if a shop has greater than 2 branches, show 2 of the branches and then have a button at the bottom of the list view that says "Show More". If possible the button would sit on top of the list, partially showing the third branch to give it a transparent gradient effect something similar to [this](https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/fadeoutreadmore.png). Clicking on the button would ideally animate the ListView as it opens downward. I understand this is a big ask but I would just like to know if it is possible and a point in the right direction. I can work on a custom solution myself once I have an idea where to start.

My ListView implementation and Layout files can be seen below:

#### BranchListAdapter.java

```
public class BranchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public BranchListAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view;

    if(convertView == null) {
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop_details_branch_list_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    final HashMap<String, String> branch = getItem(position);

    TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.branch_list_item_address);
    TextView city = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.branch_list_item_city);
    TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.branch_list_item_phone);

    address.setText(branch.get("address"));
    city.setText(branch.get("city"));
    phone.setText(branch.get("phone"));

    return view;
}

public void setData(List<HashMap<String, String>> branches) {
    clear();
    if(branches != null) {
        for(HashMap<String, String> branch : branches) {
            if(!branch.get("address").equals(""))
                add(branch);
        }
    }
}
}
```

#### fragment_shop_details_branch_list_adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/branch_list_item_grid"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    grid:columnCount="2"
    grid:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:text="Address"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/branch_list_item_address"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    tools:text="31 Fitzwilliam Manor, The Island"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    grid:layout_row="0"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="City"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    grid:layout_row="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/branch_list_item_city"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    tools:text="Dublin"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    grid:layout_row="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Phone"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/branch_list_item_phone"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"
    tools:text="01 456 7890"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    grid:layout_column="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    grid:layout_row="2"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/branch_list_item_button_showmap"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/show_on_map"
    android:textColor="#0645AD"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    grid:layout_column="0"
    grid:layout_columnSpan="2"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="center"
    grid:layout_row="4"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

#### Expand List View to Full Height function

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

And finally this is how the ListView is implemented in the Fragment:

```
    mBranchListAdapter = new BranchListAdapter(getActivity());
    mBranchListAdapter.setData(mShop.getBranchDetails());
    mBranchListView.setAdapter(mBranchListAdapter);
    MiscUtils.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(mBranchListView);
```

Comment: refer this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ